# Pros and cons of @staticmethod

Tags: python, class, static-methods

If I have some (and only one) class, A, in my file with some basic method,

```
class A(B):
    def some_overrided_method()
        return {'output': True}
```

what of the following would be better to use?

- Static method inside class

  ```
  class A(B):
     def some_overrided_method(self)
         return {'output': self.do_smth()}

     @staticmethod
     def do_smth(self):
         return True
  ```
- Function outside class

  ```
  def do_smth():
     return True

  class A(B):
     def some_overrided_method(self)
         return {'output': do_smth()}
  ```
- Of just some nested method inside

  ```
  class A(B):
     def some_overrided_method(self)
          def do_smth():
              return True
         return {'output': do_smth()}
  ```

Comment: It's up to you - will it ever be used outside that method? Outside that class?

Comment: it will be used as it proveded, maybe couple of times inside of basic method, I mean what will be more pythonic and better for performance

Comment: `Static method` would great I think. As you can call it inside your overridden method or use in other methods either using class instance or by class name it self.

Comment: *"more pythonic"* - read [PEP-0008](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/). *"better for performance"* - if it ever becomes an issue, profile it and find out.

Comment: If it's going to be used from inside/outside the class _and_ you only have class `A` in your module and nothing else... it _could be_ easier to use `@staticmethod`. So when you import the module you can simply do `from A import A` and use `A.do_smth` and `A()`. You avoid using both the module's and the class' namespaces (in other words, `import A; A.do_smth; A.A`) Honestly though, the difference is very minimal. Hardly worth the debate,

Comment: staticmethods don't have an automatic `self` argument like regular methods do.

Comment: `staticmethods` don't require self as a argument as it behaves like function and can be called using any of class's instance or by class name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it doesn't do anything with the class/instance, there is no point in it being a method of the class.

Just use a normal function.
A staticmethod is very rarely useful.

The only reason I can think of for using a staticmethod is if the function makes no sense to use outside of the class.

Comment: The latter is reason enough. Typically I use them for functions that do something that requires more a line or two of code that I don't want to stick in the middle of some of body of code, especially if it's done more than once or in more than one method — the [DRY principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself).